# Need to hide a textView while scrolling a grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to hide a textView while scrolling a grid view and make the same textview visible again when the user stops scrolling.
Can anyone help me fixing this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

implement OnScrollListener and then inside the `onScroll` make the textView invisible
and in the OnScrollStateChanged method check if the scroll stopped and make it visibile again

```
private OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(ViewGroup view, int scrollState) {
         if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
         {
                 textView.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;       
         }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(ViewGroup view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                 textView.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still only onScroll() is called but not the onScrollStateChanged..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `set this method on your gridview.` it works for me. I am sure it will help you.

```
  gridAdmin.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
             {
                     text1.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;   
             }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

             text1.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE    
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still only onScroll() is called but not the onScrollStateChanged..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(ViewGroup view, int scrollState) {
        if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onScroll(ViewGroup view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalount)
    {
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but I didn't works for me...here's my code for your reference

Comment: How would `tv.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE;tv.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;` work? Shouldn't it be `tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setVisibility` in `OnScrollListener`

Example:

```
gridview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        textview.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still only onScroll() is called but not the onScrollStateChanged..

Comment: onScrollStateChanged is not called or scrollState != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE? @user3876059 Please debug and check once.

Answer (score 0):

gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    textview.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```

});

We use this code in my app and it work , I hope it will useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still only onScroll() is called but not the onScrollStateChanged..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(ViewGroup view, int scrollState) {
         if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
     {
                 mTextView.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE;       
         }
@Override
    public void onScroll(ViewGroup view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                 mTextView.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
};
```