# Android, i'm trying to hide a textView when a gridView is scrolled and make it visible once the user stops scrolling

Tags: android, onscrolllistener

In the code below, only the `onScroll` method is called and the `onScrollStateChanged` method is never called, can you please help me fix this issue:

```
mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            check_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            System.out.println("Inside onScroll");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
             {
                check_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                System.out.println("Inside onScrollStateChanged");
             }              
        }
    });
```

Comment: give it a try with switch/case...I know the onScrollListener is not so precise...if You need an example what I mean, tell me....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to hide a textView while scrolling a grid view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097443/need-to-hide-a-textview-while-scrolling-a-grid-view)